# JW Player not playing in some browsers

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior of the embedded JW Player. Generally, it plays videos fine in

- Safari 10.0.2 (Mac)
- Internet Explorer 11 (Windows)
- Edge 25.1 (Windows)
- Mobile Safari (iOS 10.2)

It also plays fine in all other browsers, but only when I open the video on the preview page in the JW Player Backend (see screenshot, tested in Chrome 55 for Mac).

[image]

However, it doesn't play when I embed the player in my Project (locally or in productivity, **even if I use the same markup used in the preview page**), but only in some browsers, including

- Chrome 55.0 (Mac)
- Opera 42.0 (Mac)
- Firefox 50.1 (Mac)
- Chrome 55.0 (Windows)
- Firefox 50.0 (Windows)

In these Browsers, the player shows the loading icon for about 1 minute, then it says "Error loading media: File could not be played" (see screenshot, tested in Chrome 55 for Mac).

[image]

However, the browsers listed at the beginning can still play the video...
And it doesn't seem to be only me, since my colleagues are experiencing the exact same problem. Can anybody help?

Here's an example embed (expires in 1 day):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://content.jwplatform.com/players/rUqzk7Ff-JGyYovz4.js?exp=1484212670&amp;sig=e492a1f9aab8910829dabae0e97a1d5a'></script>
```

Comment: Firefox and Chrome will use a custom HTML5 player to play HLS; Edge/Safari play it natively and IE uses Flash. Do you have the most recent JW Player version? There may have been bugs that they've fixed.